# iOS Error Certificate has been revoked

Tags: ios

I have a problem with my certificate.I don't know why but every 2 to 3 days I got this error :

> This certificate has been revoked

And of course my app doesn't work anymore.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you the only one with access to your iTunes Connect account?

Comment: yes I'm the only one :/

Comment: Could you check the expiry  date of your certificate ?

Comment: It expires Juin 2017

Answer (score 1):

Somebody (possibly you) revoked your certificate.

I suppose you did without knowing it, possibly because you had to sign/upload a new version of your app from another computer than the one where your private key was on.

Comment: No I'm sure I didn't and I'm the only administrator and I request for a new one and the same thing happen again after 2 to 3 days

Answer (score 0):

From your Developer portal, respective certificate (com.XXXXX) got revoked from administrator.

Please request for new certificate and continue on your work

Comment: I did and the same thing happen again :/

Comment: Please make sure Bundle identifier for the new certificate. or Code sign might point to old certificate details